# elasticsearch: how to map common character mistakes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to map common mistakes in my language, as:

xampu -> shampoo

Shampoo is an english word, but commonly used in Brazil. In Portuguese, "ch" sounds like "x", as sometimes "s" sounds like "z". We also do not have "y" on our language, but it's common on names and foreign words - it sounds like "i".

So I would like to map a character replacement, but also keep the original word on the same position.

So a mapping table would be:

```
ch -> x
sh -> x
y -> i
ph -> f
s -> z
```

I have taken a look on the "Character Filters", but it seems to only support replacement:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html

I want to form derivative words based on the original so users can find the correct word even if typed wrong. To archive this, the following product name:

```
SHAMPOO NIVEA MEN
```

Should be tokenized as:

```
0: SHAMPOO, XAMPOO
1: NIVEA
2: MEN
```

I am using the synonym filter, but with synonym I need to may every word.

Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did not get you `I want to form derivative words based on the original so users can find the correct word even if typed wrong.`. Can you elaborate why `Mapping Char Filter` is not suitable for you.

Comment: I have elaborated the question. In short: I want to add the "XAMPOO" by the SH -> X mapping, but also keep SHAMPOO (not replace it entirely).

Comment: Okk .. Got your point.

Answer (score 1):

For your usecase, [Multi-Field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) seems to suit the best. You can keep your field analyzed in two ways, one using `standard` and other using your `custom analyzer` created using `mapping Char Filter`.

It would look like:

**Index Creation**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
  "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "my_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "char_filter": [
        "my_char_filter"
      ]
    }
  },
  "char_filter": {
    "my_char_filter": {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "ch => x",
         "sh => x",
        "y => i",
        "ph => f",
        "s => z"
      ]
      }
     }
   } 
  }
}
```

**MultiField creation**

```
POST my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
   "properties": {
   "field_name": {
     "type": "text",
     "analyzer": "standard",
     "fields": {
        "mapped": {
           "type": "text",
           "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
           }
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

Above mapping would create two versions of `field_name`, one which is analyzed ising `standard` analyzer, another which is analyzed using your `custom analyzer` created.

In order to Query Both you can use `should` on both versions.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "match": {
              "field_name": "xampoo"
           }
        },
        {
           "match": {
              "field_name.mapped": "shampoo"
           }
           }
        ]
      }
    }  
  }
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thank you Richa. It solves my problem partially. We have some product names that could generate multiple possibilities, like PHYTOVEIN: FITOVEIN, PHITOVEIN, FYTOVEIN.

Comment: I guess these will be handled. What would be the value posted in document.  If you post the document as `POST my_index/my_type
{"field_name":"fitovein"}` all above variation `phytovein,fitovein,phitovein,fytovein` would be searched using above `bool` query. Please keep in mind the case of Strings